# how to replace a value when in it is in another column sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, case-when

I am currently learning how to use sql and I wanted to know how to replace a number when that number appears in another column in the same table. For example I am given a table column one being [1 2 3 2 4] and column two being [2 1 3 4 4] I want to replace the values in column two to say FOUND when that number appears in column 1, and say NOT FOUND when it is not in the column. Heres what I tried so far

```
SELECT ID
    , CASE
        WHEN P_ID = ID THEN 'FOUND'
        WHEN P_ID <> ID THEN 'NOT FOUND'
    END AS P_ID
FROM TABLE
```

P_ID would be the second column and ID would be the first column.
This is switching every entry in P_ID to NOT FOUND.

**EDIT**
    In the example provided it would return FOUND at row 3 and 5 but NOT FOUND for every other row

Comment: I don't see why it isn't returning `FOUND` in the third and last row (you have a typo in the question though, it's missing a `'` at the end of `NOT FOUND`)

Comment: Do we assume that you have 5 rows of data, consisting of the pairs {1,2}, {2,1}, {3,3}, {2,4}, {4,4}?

Comment: @Lamak In that example yes it does but in the when they don't match up I just get NOT FOUND

Comment: Your query works fine.

Comment: @isaace then why am I getting not found for every entry inside of found when a number in the second column is in the first column

Comment: It worked here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5bfec/3

Comment: @isaace it doesn't work because the 4th column in the table says not found but since there is a 4 in the ID column the row should say FOUND

Comment: WHEN P_ID = ID THEN 'FOUND' means that it equal on that same row, so on the 4th row the ID is 2 and the P_ID is 4

Comment: @isaace Ok so then how do I make it more generally meaning when P_ID is in ID then P_ID = 'FOUND'

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @isaace yeah it worked thks

Comment: Please accept the answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ID
, CASE
    WHEN P_ID IN
      (SELECT ID FROM myTable )
       THEN 'FOUND' 
    WHEN P_ID NOT IN 
      (SELECT ID FROM myTable ) 
       THEN 'NOT FOUND'
  END AS P_ID
FROM myTable
```